# No match for ‘operator<<’ (operand types are ‘std::ostream’ {aka ‘std::basic_ostream<char>’} and ‘const std::type_index’)

Tags: c++, loops, unordered-map, visitor-pattern

Actually, I'm trying to use the visitor pattern with some templates.

I want to parse my `unordered_map` which contains `type_index` and the `function` variable but I get a compilation error that I don't understand even after reading a lot of topics about it.

> error: no match for ‘operator<<’ (operand types are ‘std::ostream’ {aka ‘std::basic_ostream’} and ‘const std::type_index’)
> std::cout << i.first << i.second << std::endl;

Here is my loop which doesn't compile

```
for (auto i : functions) {
      std::cout << i.first << i.second << std::endl;
}
```

Here is my code snippet with my loop to parse and display what is inside the `unordered_map`

```
template <typename TReturn> struct AnyVisitor {
  using typeInfoRef = std::reference_wrapper<const std::type_info>;
  using function = std::function<TReturn(std::any &)>;
  std::unordered_map<std::type_index, function> functions;

  template <typename TArg> void accept(std::function<TReturn(TArg &)> f) {
    functions.insert(std::make_pair(std::type_index(typeid(TArg)),
                                    function([&f](std::any &x) -> TReturn {
                                      return f(std::any_cast<TArg &>(x));
                                    })));

    for (auto i : functions) {
      std::cout << i.first << i.second << std::endl;
    }
  }

  TReturn operator()(std::any &x) {
    try {
      auto function = functions.at(std::type_index(x.type()));

      return function(x);
    } catch (...) {
      throw std::runtime_error("No visitor registered");
    }
  }
};
```

If anyone has an idea of how to resolve it, I'll gladly take it! Thanks

Comment: What's to not get?  `std::type_index` doesn't have an `operator <<` defined.

Comment: Did you mean `std::cout << i.first.name()`?

Comment: I don't get it, I don't need to define an operator for type_index to loop on an unordered_map no ?

Comment: Not to loop, but you are trying to output it.  There is no output operator defined for `std::type_index`

Comment: @HugoS no, you need `operator<<` to be able to output a type to `std::ostream`

Comment: I forgot to define the name method to the type_index, thanks Yksisarvinen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should try to print `i.first.name()` instead of `i.first` only